# Create a new table dependant on whether a column contents = "Private" using R

Tags: r

I have the following table currently stored in R under the name `schools` and I'm looking for a method to separate the table into two depending on whether the `Status` = "Private" or "Public".

```
schools <- read.table(text = "Code  Status    Num   Letter
                             Cox        Private   133   a
                             Tend   Public    323   f
                             Folst  Private   234   i
                             Tam    Private   343   d
                             Escot  Public    433   q
                             Sandal Public    733   p
                             Salt   Public    37    m", header = TRUE)
```

I would like all schools with a `Status` of "Private" are put into schoolsPrivate which looks like:

```
schoolsPrivate <- read.table(text = "Code    Status    Num   Letter
                             Cox     Private   133   a
                             Folst   Private   234   i
                             Tam     Private   343   d", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: `df[df$Status=="Private",,drop=FALSE]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a few ways:

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

schoolsPrivate <- filter(schools, Status == "Private")

schoolsPublic <- filter(schools, Status == "Public")
```

You can also split a df using split:

```
split_list <- split(schools, schools$Status)
```

Which yields:

```
$Private
   Code  Status Num Letter
1   Cox Private 133      a
3 Folst Private 234      i
4   Tam Private 343      d

$Public
    Code Status Num Letter
2   Tend Public 323      f
5  Escot Public 433      q
6 Sandal Public 733      p
7   Salt Public  37      m
```

And assign it like:

```
schoolsPrivate <- split_list$Private
```

Comment: I think your use of `split` is the best of the three (your two plus my commented use of `[`): it uses base R (when it was not obvious `dplyr` was in use), and it handles more than just the two categories in one call.

Comment: I agree, I did call out dplyr, and have the `library` call in there as well. Split is a helpful function though.

Comment: (My point was not that you didn't call `library` ... my point was solely that it was not obvious in the OP that they were using external libraries. You weren't wrong to suggest its use, and in fact many "solutions" to questions involve suggestions for packages that "do it right/fast/easy".)